# Coldfusion ignores posted html array fields

Tags: coldfusion

I am posting an html form which multiple input names look like that: `left_impedance_TYMP[]`

However when accessing them in coldfusion, it ignores empty fields.

`FORM["left_impedance_TYMP[]"]`

Inspecting POST request seems correct.

Is there a solution on this?

Comment: The question is not clear, at least not to me.  Are you talking about checkboxes?  Also, what do you mean by empty fields?

Comment: Have a look at [sameFormFieldsAsArray](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2012/06/19/ColdFusion-10-Missing-Feature-Form-Fields-and-Arrays/).

Answer (score 4):

When you have multiple form fields of the same name, with or without brackets, both a `GET` and a `POST` ignore empty fields values.

Form:

```
<form action="brackets_process.cfm" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="foo" value="A"><br>
    <input type="text" name="foo" value="B"><br>
    <input type="text" name="foo" value="C"><br>
    <input type="text" name="foo" value="D"><br>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Processing:

```
<cfdump var="#url#" label="URL">
<p></p>
<cfdump var="#form#" label="FORM">
```

A `GET` querystring `brackets_process.cfm?foo=A&foo=B&foo=C&foo=D`

[image]

A `POST` `brackets_process.cfm`

[image]

If you add brackets to `foo[]`, the querystring is encoded and the struct key contains the brackets.

`brackets_process.cfm?foo%5B%5D=A&foo%5B%5D=B&foo%5B%5D=C&foo%5B%5D=D`

[image]

A `POST` is still a list of submitted values.

[image]

**Converting POST data to an array.**

PHP automatically converts field names that end with a bracket to an array. ColdFusion has an application.cfc setting `this.sameformfieldsasarray=true;` that @Alex [linked](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2012/06/19/ColdFusion-10-Missing-Feature-Form-Fields-and-Arrays/). Problem is that its a global setting and could change a considerable amount of existing functionality.

With that setting on, a `POST` converts the values to an array.

[image]

A `GET` sticks to a list. So if you leave out a value (B), the value of `url["foo[]']` is a list with 4 elements, where the 2nd element is empty.

[image]

Leaving a value (B) out of a `POST`, however, returns an array with 4 elements, where the 2nd value is empty.

[image]

So you need to determine if you want to make a global change that affects all current functionality or if you can add some conditional logic that checks the number of elements in a list vs. the expected number of fields.

I've written code in the past that named fields something like `name="fieldName.#counterValue#"`, then parsed the field names to set positional values in a list or array to account for empty values.